# python - read linux command output continuously

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a command that provides event stream - new message every few second.
How do I read this as it comes with python?

The standard approach with

```
def getMessage(command):
    lines = os.popen(command).readlines()
    return lines
```

waits for the command to complete, but in this command run forever. It will continue on and print new message to stdout every few seconds.
How do I pass it on to python? I want to capture all messages in the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the output line by line and process/print it. Meanwhile use `p.poll` to check if the process has ended.

```
def get_message(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        command, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    while True:
        output = p.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            yield output.strip()
```

Comment: I needed small modification: ```p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)``` but otherwise it works great, Thanks!